# simple client - server talking to each other classes in Java

Tags: java, client-server, client

I am trying to figure out why I can send messages to the client from the server but when I try the other way around (to send messages from the client to the server) the program halts like it is waiting for some action to happen.

also how to prevent the sockets from being closed immediately.

this is the code:

**Client Class**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

 public class Client {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Client aClient = new Client();


        aClient.run();


}

private Socket socket;
private PrintWriter toServer;
private BufferedReader fromServer;

public void run() {

    try {
        socket = new Socket("localhost", 9000);
        if (socket.isConnected()){
            System.out.println("CONNECTED");
        }

        fromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        toServer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());




        toServer.print("hello server");



        System.out.print(fromServer.readLine());

        toServer.close();
       socket.close();

    } catch (Exception error) {
        System.out.println("CLIENT ERROR: " + error);

    }
}
}
```

**Server Class**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net*;


public class Server {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Server aServer = new Server();
    aServer.run();

}

private ServerSocket mainSocket;
private Socket socket;
private PrintWriter toClient;
private BufferedReader fromClient;

public Server(){
  try{
      mainSocket = new ServerSocket(9000);

}
  catch (Exception error){
      System.out.print("Error :"+error);
  }
}
public void run() {
     System.out.println("WAITING FOR CLIENTS");
    try {

        socket = mainSocket.accept();

             if(socket.isConnected()) {
                 System.out.println("CONNECTED.");
             }


        fromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        toClient = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());


        System.out.println(fromClient.readLine());
        toClient.print("hello Client");
        toClient.close();

        }
     catch (Exception error) {
        System.out.println("SERVER ERROR :" + error);
    }


}


}
```

Comment: If you want to read a line, you should print a line. The server does a print - the client calls readLine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this before `toServer.print("hello server");` to `Client` class. Its read from `System.in` and send to the `Server` class:

```
BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));    

String fromUser;
while((fromUser = stdIn.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println("Client: " + fromUser);
    toServer.println(fromUser);
}
```

And to `Server` class add this, before `System.out.println(fromClient.readLine());`, its read line from client and print to `System.out`:

```
String inputLineFromClient;
while ((inputLineFromClient = fromClient.readLine()) != null) {
     System.out.println(inputLine);
}
```

Socket not closing before you invoke method close() or occurs some `Exception`.

Comment: thanks a lot mate, I flushed the stream after printing, it kinda works now, I need to study streams and sockets more. I still have doubt about what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

your server is not reading anything.
use
    fromClient.readLine();